# What is the meaning of 外 after a verb?

Tags: grammar, translation

For example, how can you translate the sentence:

前項の決定に加わる外、その他の業務を行う。

Comment: Have you tried looking up 外? Entries at [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/外) (in Japanese), [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A4%96#Japanese) (in English).  Hint: the reading for the context of your sample sentence is ほか.

Comment: I agree with @EiríkrÚtlendi - though the immediately repeated その他{ほか} right after it would suggest to me a different reading, if one were available. I almost suspect they meant to write 以外 rather than 外.

Comment: Thanks Micah. I doubt it there is a mistake, though, it comes from the by-laws of a company and the same pattern is used repeatedly. But thanks to you and Eiríkr I think I am getting the idea implied.